# Check Keycloak SSO session presence from another domain

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, keycloak, httpsession, keycloak-18

My application is on the `example.com` domain.

My Keycloak SSO is on the `sso.example.com`.

I use Keycloak 18.

Is there a way to check the SSO session presence from the same browser, from `example.com` domain? I need this to decide whether to redirect the user, from `example.com` to the Keycloak login functionality on `sso.example.com` in order to re-authenticate them on `example.com`.

My initial idea was to check the presence of the `KEYCLOAK_SESSION` cookie, but it is stored under the `sso.example.com` domain and is not accessible from the `example.com` application.

Comment: If you are using spring ouath2 as MVC in the front end itself, then you don't need to. Once you configure it properly, your new request from browser will reach spring application and it will check http session there itself. If the session has expired, it will redirect the user to Keyclock. If not, and access token had expired, it will send refresh token request to Keyclock and get new token.

Comment: If you have multiple applications at example.com then once you login on any one of them, and u send request for another one, spring will automatically redirect u to KC which checks if SSO is already there. If yes, the ouath2 exchange will happen between the spring and KC and user will continue with same KC session but different http session on spring side.

Comment: This is true for secured pages. In the case of a secured page, it will redirect the user to Keycloak, and this works fine. The issue arises with unsecured pages that also contain Login/Logout buttons. When the application's HTTP session expires, the user sees the Login button. If the user clicks this button, a seamless redirect to/from Keycloak is performed, and the user sees the Logout button. However, the user may not understand why they need to click the Login button if they are already logged in.

Comment: In this case, I would like to automatically reauthenticate the user via a login redirect without the need to press the Login button. To achieve this, I would like to check the KEYCLOAK_SESSION cookie presence in order to trigger this login process automatically.

Comment: Running into a similar issue. Were you able to figure this out, @alexanoid?

Comment: @pthor, unfortunatly no. Now, for this purpose I use my own custom cookie (created by my app, not by Keycloak)